# How to hide images in Windows 10 Search Bar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

How do I make the Search Bar in my Windows 10 taskbar appear vanilla, without any images for upcoming events/holidays?

I'm not a Windows user. I only use windows to take screenshots for other Windows users when writing documentation. For documentation purposes, I want a clean screenshot that's as close to a fresh install of Windows as possible -- without distractions that will confuse the user.

Unfortunately, I discovered today that my Windows 10 Search Bar (the one just to the right of the Windows Logo for the Start Menu) displays an illustration of Roses. When I click it, it says that today is the Portland Rose Festival.

How do I make the Windows 10 Search Bar not display such images?

Answer (score 0):

The illustration in the search box that you're referring to is called `Search Highlights`. It was added by Microsoft to Windows 10 in [March 2022](https://beebom.com/microsoft-adds-search-highlights-windows-10-update/).

### Disable `Search Highlights`

To make the illustrations in the search box go away, disable `Search Highlights`.

To disable `Search Highlights`, right click on the Search Box. Under `Search` uncheck `Show Search Highlights`

### Disable `News and Interests`

If you want to further cleanup your screenshots so that they're "vanilla," you may also want to disable `News and Interests`.

To do so, right click on the taskbar. Under `News and Interests`, check `Turn off`.